# Pandas DataFrame does not display correctly in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I want to read one csv file into Jupyter Notebook with Python's Pandas lib.
I have uploaded .csv file into jupyter notebook, and I wrote a code, but I think that my dataframe does not display correctly.
This is the code for reading the file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('text analysis.csv')
print(df)
```

And my output, when I print that dataframe looks like this:

```
       avg title word len.  avg text word len.  avg sent. len.  \
0                     5.20                4.27           11.00   
1                     4.69                4.98           26.20   
2                     5.50                4.53           21.62   
3                     4.82                4.42           15.10   
4                     6.40                5.07           36.50   
...                    ...                 ...             ...   
34205                 4.29                4.96           24.60   
34206                 4.67                4.58           13.00   
34207                 4.92                5.08           26.79   
34208                 4.09                4.72           22.23   
34209                 4.75                5.76           18.38
```

I have seen much better representation on JN, with all cells. This looks worse then when I print dataframe in idle

Comment: Similar to @Ali Barani’s answer, your second line should just be `df`, and it has to be last line of cell.  The notebook will recognize the dataframe object and display it richly when you do that. By putting `print(df)`, you are specifying to represent it as base Python would, as if you were running base Python in console or sending output to stdout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use **display()** insted of **print()** and check it.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to your code.

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)
```

This sets it to dispay the entire dataframe.